# Help identifying succulent

Tags: identification, succulents

I got this from Trader Joe's but it just said "succulent" on the tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **Peperomia ferreyrae** or happy bean, which is considered a semi-succulent.
It is a bit tricky, as it needs slightly more water than other succulents (but not overwatering) and less direct light.

More info here: https://worldofsucculents.com/peperomia-ferreyrae-pincushion-peperomia/